# Nested queries resulting in 1064 MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

The error I receive is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') as final_price, (p.products_price * m.nz_manufacturers_value /
>   c.value + p.p' at line 1

I run this query in phpMyAdmin:

```
select p.products_quantity, p.products_id, p.manufacturers_id,
        m.manufacturers_currency,p.products_price as products_price_old, p.products_shipping, p.products_tax_class_id, 
        IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) as specials_new_products_price, 
        IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) as old_final_price,
        (IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) * m.nz_manufacturers_value / c.value + p.products_shipping * 1.4) * (select value from currencies where currencies_id = 5) as final_price,
        (p.products_price * m.nz_manufacturers_value / c.value + p.products_shipping * 1.4) * (select value from currencies where currencies_id = 5) as products_price 
        from products_description pd, products p 
        left join manufacturers m on p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id 
        left join currencies c on c.code = m.manufacturers_currency 
        left join specials s on p.products_id = s.products_id, products_to_categories p2c 
        where p.products_status = '1' and p.products_id = p2c.products_id and pd.products_id = p2c.products_id and pd.language_id = '1' and p2c.categories_id = '2716'
```

and it works fine.  By from the PHP it fails.

On the website, I remove the

`select value from currencies where currencies_id = 5`

(both instances) and the PHP works fine.

So PHP doesn't like the nested select statements like this.

Is there an easy fix for this or do I need to write a separate query for the value and then apply this to the query as a variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need additional parenthesis to wrap the query (along with `IF` statement) and apply `AS` to the result, try below:

```
select p.products_quantity, p.products_id, p.manufacturers_id,
        m.manufacturers_currency,p.products_price as products_price_old, p.products_shipping, p.products_tax_class_id, 
        IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) as specials_new_products_price, 
        IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) as old_final_price,
        ((IF(s.status, s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) * m.nz_manufacturers_value / c.value + p.products_shipping * 1.4) * (select value from currencies where currencies_id = 5)) as final_price,
        (p.products_price * m.nz_manufacturers_value / c.value + p.products_shipping * 1.4) * (select value from currencies where currencies_id = 5) as products_price 
        from products_description pd, products p 
        left join manufacturers m on p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id 
        left join currencies c on c.code = m.manufacturers_currency 
        left join specials s on p.products_id = s.products_id, products_to_categories p2c 
        where p.products_status = '1' and p.products_id = p2c.products_id and pd.products_id = p2c.products_id and pd.language_id = '1' and p2c.categories_id = '2716'
```